# How can I Write 218-one-two in Textbox?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

How can I Show "218-one-two" in Textbox that has Property RightToLeft=Yes ,
I Retrieve "218-one-two" from database and i show it in text box has RightToLeft=Yes,
When I try to show this value , it had shown like this:
"one-two-213"
i used also string.format("{0:n}-{1}-{2}",number,string,string)
i didn't work.
How can I Show or format my value in this format "number-string-string"
in RightToLeft textbox???

I am not supposing to use RightToLeft for languages only I use by default arabic language in my application, but some time i receive english values in this textbox and i need to show it on like that format.

Please Help me..

Comment: We (RTL) are the bad guys in the eye of technology so live with that. If I wanted to post my phone number in an RTL textbox then I would end up with my phone number preceding my country code number!!! even though I wrote it as I say it (in the correct way).

Comment: Sorry,
I am not supposing to use RightToLeft for languages only
I use by default arabic language in my application,
but some time i receive english values in this textbox
and i need to show it on like that format.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you feel that you need the `RightToLeft` property on? A few simple tests indicate that you're not likely to be able to override this behavior; presumably it's there for a reason.

If you're just trying to right-align the text, the `TextBox` already provides a property for that. Set your control's [`TextAlign` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx) to "Right".

You're only supposed to use `RightToLeft` for languages that display text in a right-to-left format. Judging from your question, that's clearly not the case.

Comment: In Addition
I Can't Turn RightToLeft Off.

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably talking about an app that runs in a RTL culture. But you want to inject some text from a LTF culture. There are Unicode characters that indicate that certain parts of a block of text are LTR or RTL. Can you do it that way?

Comment: had to google for it :-) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/60082618-a71d-48ea-9c2f-320b6e80b585/

Comment: @rene I don't know the details, I just remember reading about it in the O'Reilly Unicode book

Comment: Hefferman: Yeah, that is ok, I never heard of it at all so I wondered if it was ever implemented. Always fun to pick-up some trivia.